# Sort Error 1004 Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I have a worksheet with a database connection and auto-filter on it I'm trying to sort, and I can't for the life of me figure out why this is not working:

```
Sub TEST()

    Workbooks("1.Receiving Worksheet Database 02 No Filter.xlsx").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:AJ").Sort key1:=Range("B"), _
        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after reading another post that suggested someone record the macro I was like "duh!", the code that works is below and I think the issues may have had to do with the database connection and the auto-filter.

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table_Query_from_Prototype"). _
        Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table_Query_from_Prototype"). _
        Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table_Query_from_Prototype[[#All],[ID]]"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects( _
        "Table_Query_from_Prototype").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Nice and simple :|